# Packagist: Create a custom package

Tags: package, composer-php, packagist

I am trying to create a private package ("private package" means only authorized people can access it through 'composer require ' command. Packagist provide an option to create private packages) using Packagist. I am able to create package using "Upload Files" option. But when I tried to download the created package using composer I am getting the following error

`Could not find a matching version of package Vendor/Package. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).`
Please help to resolve this issue.

I created packages using "Upload Files" option. And set the  "minimum-stability": "dev" in composor.json file.

Comment: What do you mean by "private package"? Did you check whether you use the correct repository if this is not a public one?

Comment: "private package" means only authorized people can access it through 'composer require ' command. Packagist provide an option to create private packages.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it